# Does the velocity of air in an engine increase in the compressor section or turbine section?

Tags: engine

I think it increases in the turbine section because the pressure and temperature decrease so the velocity increases but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Air velocity increases in the turbine section.

In order to compress air, we need to apply work on it, like running a car engine harder to drive it up the hill. Part of the work required comes from decelerating the air that flows into the engine.

The work done can be released by accelerating the gas and letting it escape, creating thrust. The expanding gas also applies work on the turbine blades, which absorb part of the accumulated energy. Each turbine stage slows down the gas, but from a higher velocity base due to the expansion. In the turbine section as a whole, gas velocity is increased.

The faster the gas flows out of the engine, the higher the thrust that is created.

Comment: Actually the velocity of the gas varies throughout the engine.  However the gas expands and actually slows as it passes through the turbine section (it has to as it is converting its internal and kinetic energy into mechanical energy for the turbine.  Gas is accelerated, however, as it passes through the diffuser (nozzle) at the end of the jet pipe.

Comment: @Notts90 The incoming air is decelerating now.